# How to weight paint only one axis without affecting sides of object?

Tags: particles, texture-painting, weight-painting

I only want to weight paint the top part of my design, yet it leaks down onto the sides.

Is there a way to weight paint only one side of an object?

[image]

even when I only select the top faces, it still leaks through the sides as shown in the photo

Comment: could you please share your file or at least show your wireframe?

Comment: if you restrict [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6lR.png to a vertex group [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InI8M.png you get this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJNxZ.png and of course if you add another "sharp" loop cut [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQFSf.png you will get: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHsLh.png

Comment: @chris so some reason it worked first time but blender crashed so I tried it again and now when I try to weight paint it doesn't paint and like only one tiny corner gets paint, which makes no sense

Comment: update I forgot to assign the vertex group, so now it works!!

Comment: glad i could help